# Windows 10 and UTF-8

Tags: windows-10, putty

I am trying to send UTF-8 data through a serial connection to a device using either Putty or ZOCterm. I can receive UTF-8 data, but not send it. I think it is a windows10 thing. I enabled use UTF-8 for world wide language support, but that did not help. When I try to paste 地饭图台要同换很或就和或 into the terminal window it ends up like this:e?0i%-e e?0i%-e e?0i%-e

Is there any way I can make this work?